# AWS sync with --delete option set to ignore a folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the aws sync an S3 bucket, it has content at the root and in a specific folder - let's call it `files/`.
I am using the delete option because I want to remove the files that don't exist in destination in the source as well but just in the root folder. The folder `files/*` I want to keepintact.
Would that be possible with any of the command's options?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "I want to remove the files that don't exist in destination in the source"? When the `sync` process uses `--delete`, it will delete objects in the _destination_ that now longer exist in the _source_. Is that what you were wanting?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can combine two `sync` commands to get the desired result:

```
aws s3 sync <from> <to> --delete --include "*" --exclude "files/*"
aws s3 sync <from> <to> --exclude "*" --include "files/*"
```

The first one should `sync` all files with the delete flag except the ones in `files/` and the second one should sync only files in the `files/` directory. Please be aware that the order of the filter parameters (`--include` / `--exclude`) plays a role, see [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) for an example.
Hope this helps!